# For loop conversion from R to python for iterating pandas dataframes

Tags: python, r, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to convert the following `R script to Python`. I am able to convert the `individual lines of code to python`. But could not find a way to apply `for loop`, as the following lines use the `iterator variable i`.
`date is datetime data type, week is string type`. There are 3 data frames.`length of new_levels` is greater than `df2$week unique(), levels`
Got stuck with this `for loop` for sometime.

```
df <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:NROW(df2)){
  temp <- subset(df1,df1$ID == df2$ID[i] & df1$week <= df2$week[i])
  temp_1 <- temp[order(factor(temp$week, levels = new_levels)),]
  temp <- tail(temp_1,6)
  
  temp$bookid <- df2$bookid[i]
  temp$plan <- df2$plan[i]
  temp$date <- df2$date[i]
  
  if(nrow(temp)>1){
    for(j in 1:NROW(temp)){
      temp$date[j] <- (temp$date[j] - (NROW(temp)-j)*24*3600*7)
    }
    temp1 <- temp[-nrow(temp),]
    df <- rbind(df,temp1)
  }
```

Comment: Never call `rbind` in a for-loop. It leads to excessive copying. Instead build a list of data frames and call `rbind` once.

Comment: Also, please show Python attempt so we can help with your implementation. Like [R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451), please set up Pandas [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451).